# Why UIView setFrame not working inner for loop in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, progress-bar

```
UIView *test=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 150, 10, 20)];
[test setBackgroundColor:[Util colorWithHexString:@"#FF00007f"]];
[self.view addSubview:test];
int testNum=0;
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    testNum=0;
    //do something spend 100 ms
    while(testNum<800){
        testNum+=1;
    }
    [test setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 150, 10+i*200/50, 20)];
}
```

I want to build a custom progress bar.

Just like above, but the uiview only redraw by last one of loop.

How can I resolve the problem? And, what happen?

Thanks.

I change code to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    int testNum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        testNum=0;
        while(testNum<800){
            NSLog(@"%d",testNum);
            testNum+=1;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [test setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 150, 10+i*200/50, 20)];
        });

    }
});
```

It work, but while loop just simulate situations for block code in my project.

Actually, spend time code is alloc list item and initial it's view, so it necessary in main thread.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You are going to need to look into and learn about "Concurrency Programming" or "Multi-Threading", or one of a number of other terms and systems Apple offers (Global Distribution Center). Basically, just think of your problem as "I say in code to do 100 things", but the the act of "updating the screen" can only happen after those 100 things, even if those 100 things all say "make the screen do something".

Comment: I don't have much else to say about your new code, as what you have is theoretical and not actual. I can say that arbitrarily timing a progress bar is not a typical implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I remove the for loop. Then load one list item after progress bar redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Your "do something spend 100 ms" loop takes just a few cycles to execute on the iPhone, your code is working but it's not stalling long enough for any visible progress to be seen.

Also it's very bad practice to try and lock up the UI thread like that.

Comment: That would imply that the screen will redraw during a while loop? I might have my head down in SpriteKit too far, but doesn't that loop require multi-threading to show a visual update during a for/while loop?